# Child process setInterval sporadically not firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval, child-process

My application places bets on certain sporting events. Almost like an automatic betting bot. A part of this is to track the current status of the event so it can make an informed calculation whether to place a bet or not. To do this, I poll the status of an event every minute using `setInterval`. A single sporting event is "watched" by **1** child process. There could be up 100+ sporting events at any one time meaning there could be 100+ child process' spawned & actively polling.

**`worker/index.js`**

```js
const logger = require('../lib/logger/winston')
const utils = {
    updateEventState: require('../utils/update-event-state')
}
const db = require('../db')

let eventStatesInterval

module.exports = async function() {
    try {
        logger.info(`[STARTED FOR EVENT ${process.EVENT_ID} (Process: ${process.pid})]`)

        const event = await db.getEvent(process.EVENT_ID)

        logger.info(`[STARTING STATE POLLING FOR EVENT (${process.EVENT_ID} - Process: ${process.pid})]`)

        eventStatesInterval = setInterval(utils.updateEventState, 60000, event) // 1 min

        process.on('exit', code => {
            clearInterval(eventStatesInterval)
        })
    } catch(err) {
        throw err
    }
}
```

**`utils/update-event-state.js`**

```js
const logger = require('../lib/logger/winston')
const db = require('../db')

module.exports = async function(event) {
    try {
        const update = {}

        if (!process.CHECKING_EVENT) {
            process.CHECKING_EVENT = true

            logger.info(`[POLLING STATE (${process.EVENT_ID} - Process: ${process.pid})]`)

            // Some async operations polling APIs to get the full status of an event
            const hasEnded = await api.getHasEventEnded(process.EVENT_ID)

            await db.updateEvent(process.EVENT_ID, update)

            if (hasEnded) {
                process.exit(0)
            }
            process.CHECKING_EVENT = false
        }
    } catch(err) {
        throw err
    }
}
```

It's also worth noting that a single child process *could* have more `setInterval` process' further down the line. For example, if I place a bet that is not fully matched. I poll to check when/if it gets matched. This is also run on a `setInterval` basis *(about every 5 secs)*. Check ing the logs, some process' are polled correctly every minute but a couple *(inconsistent number each time)* are not being polled at all. Looking at the logs for a specific process, I get:

[image]

*For reference, the current time was 22:33 when that screenshot was taken so the interval had not happened in over an hour*

There was only 4 events *(child process')* running at the time.

That is an **example** screenshot. A process can log several interval callbacks & then just...stop. No more logs at all. No errors or anything. Just stops.

This application runs on a Digital Ocean box with 4GB memory & 2 vCPUs. The app is dockerised. When running `docker stats`, 100% CPU is being used constantly. When starting with `docker run`, I limit the memory usage but not the CPU. Could this be the issue? Would `setInterval` callback liable not be invoked due to CPU constraints?

It's worth noting that this feature to poll the event state is new *(5 days)* & I had **never** had an issue with `setInterval` beforehand *(I don't know how much CPU was being used though)*. I was initially polling the state every 30 seconds & when I noticed this problem. When I checked `docker stats`, almost 200% CPU usage was shown. Lowering it to 1 minute instead has fixed that slightly. I have the [`process.CHECKING_EVENT` global bool there to not block the thread](https://dev.to/akanksha_9560/why-not-to-use-setinterval--2na9) & not cause a pile up of tasks on the stack.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using child **processes** instead of doing it in-proc? The whole point of NodeJS (at least, _traditionally_) is that you only need one process per hardware thread (i.e. CPU core) because NodeJS **very** efficiently handles asynchrony.

Comment: shouldnt you set `process.CHECKING_EVENT` to false *inside* the if?

Comment: @James yes it should, that's just a mistake in the writing of the question but is correct in the code, I'll edit it

Comment: @Dai are you referring to handling an event per child process or just the polling of the event state? If the former, it was a design decision to sandbox each event in it's own process & other constraints imposed by external APIs. I spin these process' up on a schedule depending on the start time of the event. If referring to the latter of polling the event state, this is actually a really good idea & had not thought of it, thank you!